# To print the value inside an Unsigned character pointer

Tags: c++, c, pointers

What is the use of unsigned char stream.

If I am having an unsigned character stream as below , how can i print the values inside that stream.

For an ordinary character stream or string i can print it using %s, but what about this.

Thanks in advance.

```
unsigned char *ptr ="(some value)"
```

Comment: `%s` will work fine. Also, in general `char` may or may not be `signed`.

Comment: @Keith and KarthikT isn't a mismatching type and conversion specifier undefined behavior?

Comment: @H2CO3. True. But `%s` merely requires `an array of character type`, which can be `char, signed char or unsigned char`.

Comment: @H2CO3: C.11 §7.21.6.1 on **`s`**: *If no `l` length modiﬁer is present, the argument shall be a pointer to the initial element of an array of character type.*

Answer (score 8):

When it comes to string handling, there is no notable difference between `unsigned char` and plain `char`. The latter can be either signed or unsigned, it is implementation-defined. However, all symbol tables always have positive index. So when you are dealing with strings, you can always safely cast between `unsigned char` and `char`. (Pointer casts between the two types are formally poorly defined behavior by the standard, but in reality, it will always work on any system ever made.)

Thus `printf("%s", ptr);` will work fine.

Answer (score 3):

An unsigned char array usually represents raw byte data and if you want to output that as a string by using `%s`, you'll probably get gibberish characters, that'll be of no meaning to you.
If you really wish to see the values, then i recommend conversion of a single byte to `short` and then output it with a `%i`.

Just my opinion.

Comment: Agreed. You should think about the future usage of your unsigned char ptr -- are you going to use it with regular C-strings, or with 'raw memory' bytes? Planning ahead and using the proper type ensures the compiler is able catch a class of possible errors.

Comment: If I know its being used as byte data, then I use %x.